# I don't know how to build the visual I want

Tags: matrix, powerbi

I'm trying to build a specific matrix on Power BI Desktop, but I can't and I don't know either if I could do it, I'll explain:

I have 4 columns in my table, 3 of them are categories, and the last one is a date column, so I want to build a matrix which allows me to put that 3 columns without be a hierarchical order, one next to each other, I will try to paint what I want:

```
              2019-10      2019-11      2019-12 
X   Y   Z        40           45           57
X   Y   Z        41           50           1
X   Y   Z        40           45           57
```

I just can do it hierarchicaly or concatenating columns, but having different lengths, they are not aligned.

How can I do what I want?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried the matrix visual?

Comment: Yes and I just can do it hierarchicaly or concatenating columns

Answer (score 0):

In visualization tag->Format->Row headers->Staggered design->OFF